# PHP best practices : do you use ; after each PHP statement or not?

Tags: php

I'm still pretty new to PHP so I don't want to make any bad habits early. When I input this statement into a WordPress PHP file:

```
<p>This post was written by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```

It also works when I remove the semicolon:

```
<p>This post was written by <?php the_author() ?></p>
```

Is it a bad practice if I do not use a semicolon at the end of my php statements or not?

Comment: Why do I see semicolon discussion everywhere nowadays? Why this doesn't stop!

Comment: It doesn't change anything, it's implicit, much like `return 0;` at the end of `main()` in C++. It's also a bit like asking "which one tastes better, tea or coffee?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't required but I would argue it is best practice too, that way you can add other lines after it easily if you need to. It also gets you in the habit of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! The WordPress Codex also always lists semicolons at the end of all of their statement, so going from them, and what everyone else is saying, it sounds like it would be a good idea to leave them in there for long term scalability.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you put a semicolon after a statement, so you should put one here. Though you are allowed to omit it in this case, if you would put an extra statement in there you'd have to add it. That would be strange in my opinion: you need to add something to a previous line because you added an extra statement. Confusing.

Comment: What @Nanne said is absolutely correct! If someone came along to work on your previous work, they'd need to add things which they technically shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the closing php tag `?>` implies a semi-colon so it is not necessary for single function calls, this on the other hand would cause a parse error:

```
<?php do_something() str_repeat('23', 4) ?>
```